# Db_select Condition Collate

Tags: 7, database

In drupal 7 db_query, when i use (**LIKE**), i add (**COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci**) after field. Because i want to search by Turkish characters. It works fine.

But i dont know how i use this in db_select. For example;
I use that condition

```
$query->condition('title', '%' . db_like($some_text) . '%', 'LIKE');
```

And i use orderby like that

```
$query->orderBy('title', 'ASC')
```

How can i add **COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci** for condition and order?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution now.

For LIKE;

```
$query->where('n.title COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci LIKE :title', array(':title' => '%'.db_like($some_text).'%'));
```

For ORDER BY;

```
$query->orderBy('n.title COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci', 'ASC');
```